# Running a program with parameters in AutoHotKey

Tags: windows-7, bash, script, shell-script, autohotkey

I have the following AutoHotKey script:

```
NumpadPgDn::
Run C:\cygwin64\bin\mintty.exe, B:\Users\User\Desktop - 
Return
```

The dash at the end of the second line (`-`) needs to be appended as a parameter/argument to the program, but it's breaking the script and causing `mintty.exe` to open at /cygwin/b instead. How can I fix the script so that the dash is successfully sent as a parameter to `mintty.exe`?

Comment: `Run, C:\cygwin64\bin\mintty.exe -, B:\Users\User\Desktop` ;)

Comment: NO problem, You see, I know something, not only cygwin :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such invocation might do what you want

```
NumpadPgDn::
Run, C:\cygwin64\bin\mintty.exe -, B:\Users\User\Desktop
Return
```